# Advice needed - automate everything or only new/current projects

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I watched Klaus Ita Keynote on FreeCodeCamp YouTube channel about devops and got inspired.

In previous job we had very good deployment system. We begun with Jenkins and pulling source from SVN, and then migrated over GitHub and used CircleCI. We also managed to use only single source code for many clients using multi tenancy approach, so everything was simplified to the bare minimum.

Now I started to work in another company, digital agency, and 80% of current projects are Wordpress.

I don’t think that we would be able to merge all clients under one source code (or we could try with multi tenancy, by managing seperate databases, seperating out plugins and themes), but at the moment all the projects are just copied to server via FTP. At least, GIT is used to keep versions.

I have in my mind, that I would really like to improve this deployment process by automating it as much as possible, at least with Jenkins and git-ftp, but th question is how to start doing this? I mean, move one-by-one project to Jenkins or only those that requires future upgrades? Or only new projects, that might come in? Is it worth that effort? What should we do with rest of 20% of custom projects?

I hope that you might share your experience, your failures and know-how’s to help one more soul to sleep better at night :)

Answer (score 1):

You can spend a lot of time, to automate something, which is done monthly and do routine staff manually on a daily basis - not the best way.

If you are time/resource limited, then find the bottleneck in the software delivery process and improve it, after that bottleneck is not a bottleneck anymore, find a new one and so on. So if you are spending 80% of your development time/resources on the new project, automate it first, and leave the old ones for the next step or vice a versa, depending where the main bottleneck is.

Comment: Thank you, very useful insight about the bottleneck approach!